# Websites/Webuilding- How Domain names works

Tags: subdomain

**Well, for background-**

> I'm interested in many things, one of which is Web-building. But I
> have very-very basic knowledge in the sphere. Even less than basic.
>
> Last night, I wanted to update my Flash player, and went to adobe's
> site to download. Was odd when I noticed the URL for the Fplayer was
> **get2.adobe.com**. Other products such as Reader/Air/etc had **get**, not
> **get2** as their 3rd level-domain. I've seen few more sites as this.

Now nevertheless if this was a redirection to a fake site or such, my question is:
Is 3rd level domain's owner is the same owner of 2nd-domain?

In the quote, does **get2.adobe.com** is basically 100% adobe's sub-address? So is as far as something is under **adobe.com** (**YOLO.adobe.com**, etc) is their's site? If no, was it sort of hijack or such?

Also, if I have a domain name, a server, etc. Can I make infinite sub-domains, or do I need to register/buy every one of them(**something**'s)- **something3.something2.somthing1.MyDomain.com**?

**Mainly looked for answer at wiki:**
[Domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), [Top level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), [Second and lower levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Second-level_and_lower_level_domains).

Thank you in advance. Hope all according to rules, and such. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of a domain name does *not* register individual subdomains; the owner only registers the one *domain level*, and he can freely create as many lower-level subdomains as he wants.

**You do not need to doubt that Adobe *owns* get2.adobe.com.** Adobe Systems Incorporated is the rightful owner of **adobe.com**, which is a *second-level domain name*. (**.com** is the *top-level domain name*.) Adobe Systems is therefore the owner of all deeper third-, fourth-, fifth-level subdomains etc. (There can be up to 127 levels.)

Be aware that domains are registered at different levels. While **.com** allows registration of second-level domains, other domains are registered at the third level. For example, Adobe also owns **adobe.co.uk**, which is a third-level domain name, and therefore **www.adobe.co.uk**. But they do not own **co.uk** or **example.co.uk**.

If you are concerned about the *trustworthiness* of a website, then **if the site uses *HTTPS*, you should verify the SSL certificate**, no matter if you recognize the domain or not. Even though we know that Adobe is the rightful owner of adobe.com and all subdomains, it is still possible that a malicious agent on the Internet network is posing as adobe.com or intercepting traffic intended for an adobe.com server. If you are sending sensitive information to the adobe.com server, make sure it uses HTTPS and the certificate is valid. Your browser will warn you if the certificate is not valid.

Unfortunately, Adobe doesn't appear to have configured get2.adobe.com properly for HTTPS.

You might be interested in this answer over at Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/a/109483/183554

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer, yours and Elias's! Very helpful, and touched the points I wanted. Darn, I need to chose only one best answer :(

Answer (score 3):

When you register a domain you declare to your registrar the DNS servers that will be responsible for providing the IP address of your web / email / whatever server(s) each time they receive a request by a client for one of your domains / sub-domains.

This means that if you registered the main domain, your are the sole owner of all it's possible sub-domains because you are the one configuring the DNS name-server who will ultimately decide the ip address the request resolves when someone hits your website or your other services. You can even redirect some / all sub-domains to other DNS servers or make them point to external servers not managed by you (of course you must want this to happen).

Alternatively you can choose someone to configure all this for you and usually this is automatically configured by your web hosting provider when you create a new site / domain in the administration panel he usually provides to you.

Either way, unless the aforementioned DNS server or any application server in general in the hosting provider is compromised, there is no way for a sub-domain not to be owned and managed by the owner of the main domain or at least know and willingly decide who serves the user requests.

And yes, if you own the domain example.com you can have as many sub-domains of whatever depth as you wish (e.g sub.example.com or sub.sub.example.com etc) without registering them separately and / or paying anything extra. The only thing you have to do is configure your web and dns servers to accept requests on each subdomain you want. This is also automatically done by using your web hosting provider's administration panel.

Here's a cool youtube video to help you understand how the DNS system works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72snZctFFtA

Hope something from the above is helpful in your understanding on this subject as I can't really guess what you might already know. There's always the possibility that you already know most of my answer!

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer, yours and Andres's! Very helpful, and touched the points I wanted. Darn, I need to chose only one best answer :(